# Почему событие срабатывает без клика?

Tags: javascript

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', alert(123));
```

```html
<button>ok</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Потому что это `alert(123)` - вызов функции `alert`.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  alert(123);
});
```

```html
<button>ok</button>
```